# Why do I have to wait 24 hours before awarding a Bounty for existing answer?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I have just started a bounty to reward [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/50450/21267).

I chose the bounty reason of 'Reward existing answer'.
[image: Bounty reason - Existing answer]

But when I tried to immediately award the bounty, the following error message popped-up:
[image: Bounty error message]

**Why is this so?**

- I said I want to award an **existing answer**, so I don't need to wait for a new one
- Is it to raise awareness of the question in the 'featured' tab for (minimum) a day?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116072/172958

Comment: @Kevin I should really learn to look at MSO before posting here :) Would that make this a dupe?

Comment: We don't close questions as dupes of something on another site.

Comment: hmm, I might take some time and compile the available reasons and catalog them here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some of the reasons, based on the discussions and answers supplied in the [relevant MSO discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer):

- **[Feature the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116073/252593)**, as per [regular bounty protocols](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), the question will have the chance to be 'Featured' and attract attention. This can:

  - Provide a chance for the question to get more high-quality answers and up-votes
  - Provide a chance for the existing answer(s) to get more up-votes
- **[Prevent Misuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118443/252593)**, the SE staff have [noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer#comment602329_123761) that people are using the bounty transfers as a means of passing reps to their mates. [Shog9 ◆](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)  says:

  > I've had the dubious privilege of seeing even more dodgy tricks played with bounties - and frankly, I tend to think they're too easy to award already.

  Limiting the bounty award to 24 hours can:

  - Deter [Nefarious](http://ratchet.wikia.com/wiki/Nefarious) (no not that one) activity
- **[Give others a chance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118477/252593)**, As [Jeff Atwood ◆](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) says:

  > If you start a bounty, part of your contract with the community is to allow everyone to have a shot at potentially earning it with a great answer.